# Is Stack Exchange a good model for UX

Tags: discussion

As UX is primarily opinion based, are people asking questions fighting a losing battle given the remit of SE as a primarily Q&A site?

Oftentimes, especially with UX, people want opinions and give theirs.

Comment: Your statement is opinion based, but good answers are research based. The answer is kind of worthless without research to support your words.

Answer (score 0):

Answers can be opinion based, but they can't be *primarily* opinion based.  That is the issue.

While many people want more specific reviews and opinions, that isn't suited well to a Q&A type site.  That said, a discussion forum wouldn't have many of the benifits of a Q&A type site like Stack Exchange.  In my opinion we need both Q&A type sites and discussion type sites (of which there are many).

Comment: I see what you are saying, although sometime I want somewhere to ask, "what's your opinion on this?" Where do you ask those sorts of Q's then?

Comment: Typically in chat, but it's been quiet for a while.  Or I ask other UX professionals that I know.  There's not yet a fantastic solution to a "what's your opinion on this?" type question.